# plotly cannot find nbformat even though it's there (jupyter notebook)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

```py
from plotly import optional_imports
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

import plotly.express as px

# Proof that nbformat is installed.
assert not (not nbformat or LooseVersion(nbformat.__version__) < LooseVersion("4.2.0"))

fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

gives

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_898/3832418673.py in <module>
      7 
      8 fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
----> 9 fig.show()

/opt/conda/envs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3396         import plotly.io as pio
   3397 
-> 3398         return pio.show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3399 
   3400     def to_json(self, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/conda/envs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py in show(fig, renderer, validate, **kwargs)
    395 
    396         if not nbformat or LooseVersion(nbformat.__version__) < LooseVersion("4.2.0"):
--> 397             raise ValueError(
    398                 "Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed"
    399             )

ValueError: Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed
```

Comment: What does `!pip show nbformat` return?

Comment: I am having the same problem and `!pip show nbformat` shows version 5.1.3

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Upgrade nbformat

> pip install --upgrade nbformat

**2.** Restart your Kernel

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Anaconda with Python 3.9 and nbformat 5.7.3. My code was running in a Jupyter Notebook in VSCode on Windows 11.

Downgrading nbformat to 5.1.2 solved this issue for me.

```
pip install nbformat==5.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you are not installing nbformat within a different environment or python version. In my case I had the same problem and the kernel I was using was python 3.11 but pip install installed on the python 3.9.

So, when I did `$ pip install nbformat` it would install for python 3.9 and my code was running on python 3.11.

The solution was to install explicitly with
`$ pip3.11 install nbformat`